# Is there something similar to the selenium grid when using cucumber/capybara?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, selenium-grid

So I'm trying to get an environment set up that acts like a selenium grid in that:
1) It runs the tests in parallel across a distributed set of clients
2) I can specify tests to run on specific clients (which are running on different OS's, with different browsers), or tests to run once on all the clients or any combination thereof.

The problem is that capybara actually currently uses WebDriver, not selenium, so as far as I know I can't specify a selenium grid for the tests to hook up to and have it work.

I've looked into things such as [DeepTest](http://deep-test.rubyforge.org/) and [Testjour](https://github.com/brynary/testjour#readme), but neither scratches both itches above. I'd love for there to be a way I can tag a cucumber feature with what browsers I want it run on, and it just does it, like selenium grid currently does. Is there an easy way I can do this without a lot of hackery on my part, or do I need to wait for Selenium 2 to be released?
Oh and I should add I've love to keep capybara's ability to swap out web drivers at will - running on selenium (or WebDriver I guess I should say), htmlunit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a version of grid for webdriver under development.

You can find info about it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/6d9d022ab0411885/ffb846e0f4723133?lnk=gst&q=grid#ffb846e0f4723133)

Comment: I'll certainly check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So one potential solution I'm digging into here is [Hydra](https://github.com/ngauthier/hydra/wiki). It seems to work for parallel execution of cucumber scenarios across multiple machines simply using ssh, thus scratching itch #1 above. I've set it up and have it running properly on two macs and a windows VM, and things are running smoothly. However, itch #2 remains unscratched. So I [forked](https://github.com/ccthiel/hydra) it, and my first pass is to simply set up a way to run *all* features on *all* machines in a parallel manner, ensuring that all features get tested on every supported browser we have. My next pass may be to hack in a way to to be able to specify which features run on which machines, if time permits and the need is great enough. We'll see how it goes.